# Php Dynamic page cache Content Encoding Error

Tags: php, html, cache-control

I am trying to make a page cache in PHP.
First when i add this line `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` to turn on output buffering my firefox browser will show this error

> **Content Encoding Error**
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown
>   because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression. Please
>   contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

While on chrome i get this error

> **This site can’t be reached**
>
> The webpage at http://example.conm/index
>   might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
>   web address. ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

This is the code I am using before it was working but I don't know what is wrong.

```
    <?php
$dynamiccatch = true;
    //Catch method Enable this function in Define.php
    if($dynamiccatch == true && (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['cjladmin']))){ 
    $cache_ext  = '.html'; //file extension
    $cache_time     = 3600;  //Cache file expires after these seconds (1 hour = 3600 sec)
    $cache_folder   = 'cache/'; //folder to store Cache files
    $ignore_pages   = array('', '');
    $dynamic_url    = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // requested dynamic page (full url)
    $cache_file     = $cache_folder.md5($dynamic_url).$cache_ext; // construct a cache file
    $ignore = (in_array($dynamic_url,$ignore_pages))?true:false; //check if url is in ignore list

    if (!$ignore && file_exists($cache_file) && time() - $cache_time < filemtime($cache_file)){ //check Cache exist and it's not expired.
        ob_start('ob_gzhandler'); //Turn on output buffering, "ob_gzhandler" for the compressed page with gzip.
        readfile($cache_file); //read Cache file
        echo '<!-- cached page - '.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', filemtime($cache_file)).', Page : '.$dynamic_url.' -->';
        ob_end_flush(); //Flush and turn off output buffering
        exit(); //no need to proceed further, exit the flow.
    }
    //Turn on output buffering with gzip compression.
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    ######## End catch technology #########
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title><?php echo 'Index | '.WebName;?></title>
        <?php include('meta.php');?>
      </head>
      <body>
    My website here
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php 
    if($dynamiccatch == true && (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['cjladmin']))){
    ######## Catch footer ends here #########
    if (!is_dir($cache_folder)) { //create a new folder if we need to
        mkdir($cache_folder);
    }if(!$ignore){
        $fp = fopen($cache_file, 'w');  //open file for writing
        fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents()); //write contents of the output buffer in Cache file
        fclose($fp); //Close file pointer
    }ob_end_flush(); //Flush and turn off output buffering
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please fix the format of your code

Comment: @VuralAcar that is my problem i have been trying to get it don for more than 24 hours but still don't know what to do again

Comment: I am sure it's the problem with `utf-8 file` with an `UTF-8 BOM` inside

Comment: @VuralAcar i think is true i removed everything include at the top of the code and it word so let me figure out where it is from

Comment: Are you using Notepad++?

Comment: @VuralAcar yes am using it and i was unable to find what the problem is i have see once file once i remove it will work but i couldn't see line that is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

What causes problem with your page is UTF-8 BOM

- A UTF-8 BOM'ed file-string will start with the following bytes. `EF BB BF` which are `ï»¿` chars.

You should change page's enconding from `UTF-8 BOM` to `UTF-8`. This should solve your problem.

There are few or less IDE's that causes it happen without letting you know about it.

Example situation:

```
-> File Edited 
-> File Saved (UTF-8)
-> File Uploaded (File encoding changed to UTF-8 BOM)
```

If this happens, set your IDE's Enconding from default to 'UTF-8 Without BOM'.

As you describe in your comment, you are using Notepad++

I would only recommend using Notepad++ only to preview files but not for development, if you want to you Notepad++ for development aswell, then you should configure it correctly like below:

```
Goto `Encoding`  and select the `Encoding in UTF-8 without BOM` option.
```

**What is a BOM?**

> A byte order mark (BOM) consists of the character code U+FEFF at the beginning of a data stream, where it can be used as a signature defining the byte order and encoding form, primarily of unmarked plaintext files. Under some higher level protocols, use of a BOM may be mandatory (or prohibited) in the Unicode data stream defined in that protocol.

**Where is a BOM useful?**

> A BOM is useful at the beginning of files that are typed as text, but for which it is not known whether they are in big or little endian format—it can also serve as a hint indicating that the file is in Unicode, as opposed to in a legacy encoding and furthermore, it act as a signature for the specific encoding form used.

Comment: am using UTF-8 in my Notepad++

Comment: But Notepad++ changes it to UTF-8 BOM, thats why I have asked, if you are using Notepad++ ;)

Comment: Which once is more better to for development and how do i change it UTF-8 once i get a better one?

Comment: I can recommend to use PHPStorm for PHP Development, or Netbeans. Both are Fullstack Web Development IDEs

Comment: Just change the setting as I described above and  Save as.. your file again with UTF-8 Encoding